# Add Google Map places to my own cloud database, later to be geofence queried on client app

Tags: android, firebase, google-places-api, android-geofence, geofire

I am working on an android app, in which, there is a google map, I want a user to add Places and save, this place won't be saved in google maps but to any realtime cloud database which can be seen by all the app user while in the geofence.

I need help!
Which real-time cloud database can be used to store the places? and how to query and retrieve by geofence?
Thanks!